# I am implementing search and when i put nothing in search box this must be remain on same page what will be java script coding for that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing search and when i put nothing in search box this must be remain on same page what will be java script coding for that.

i just create function in java script and return false if string is null on button click it is not working.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkForm(form){
    if(form.searchText.value == ''){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>

Comment: <form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
  <input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>

Comment: Beneath your question, there's a semi-obvious link titled "edit". Please use that to edit your question with new information instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 5):

As your text makes no sense I must guess what you want to say.
You want your search form to not submit if field is empty and user clicks on search

on form attributes you use [onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
  <input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

now you check if `searchText` has any text and return `true` or `false`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkForm(form){
    if(form.searchText.value == ''){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can i call this function on onclick of button.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to use JQuery for this kind of functionality, eg:
for the following form

```
<form action="/myaction" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="" name="something1" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="something2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in the same HTML file or in a separate JS file included via html HEADERS :

```
$(function () {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
          return ($(this).children("input").val()=='') ? false : true;
    });
});
```

or if you don't like ternary expression:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        doSubmit = true;
        if ($(this).children("input").val()=='') {
            doSubmit = false;
        }
        return doSubmit;
    });
});
```

Using it this way, the function assume that all the fields of the form are not empty before posting data.

One other advantage of this method is that it doesn't alter the view code (this is some no intrusive javascript fashion) and can be much more easy to work with.

Hope it help.

Comment: and you say that for a beginner is much easier to work with ``return ($(this).children("input").val()=='') ? false : true;`` than with ``if(form.searchText.value == '')``?

Comment: I think using JQuery like framework is a good way to implements clear javascript. Perhaps the ternary expression is not really clear for a beginner.

Comment: I have ommitted the $(function () { .... }); jquery tag. Sorry about that. This way you can put your JS code wherever you want.